# Minimum number of elements required to make sum?

Tags: number-theory

I want the minimum number of elements to get a required sum.

```
For Example:Sum=4
            N=3 {1,2,3} is enough since (1+3 = 4)
```

Comment: Without any constraints, the answer is just $1$ element: the number itself. I presume you want more constraints than this though?

Comment: @peterwhy If that were the case `{1}` is sufficient :P

Comment: No we have to use number once

Comment: I want the range not the number of elements that will make the desired sum

Answer (score 1):

If you have the set $\{1,2,3\dots n\}$ you can get the numbers $1,2,3  \dots ,\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

so all you have to do is given a value of $k$ find the least $n$ so that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\geq k$

That number is going to be one of $\lfloor\sqrt{2k}\rfloor,\lfloor\sqrt{2k}+1\rfloor$.